# Do scriptures mention the presence of the Egyptians in the Holy Land after Yehoshua's conquer?

Tags: history, tanach, eretz-yisrael, egypt

Archaeological [sources](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C) (only an example) mention such presence/influence in the time of the conquer which gradually faded before David's Kingdom.

Is it mentioned anywhere in the Nac"h that the Egyptians resided in the Holy Land in the times or after Yehoshua's conquer?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.30.11?lang=bi

Comment: @JoelK I didn't mean "*וַיִּמְצְאוּ אִישׁ־מִצְרִי בַּשָּׂדֶה ...׃"*, I meant a settlement.

Comment: The example you bring only mentions conquest of the Holy Land (and "decimation" of it's people) by an Egyptian king, not that Egyptians settled there. If you want an example of a post-Yehoshua Egyptian military campaign to the Holy Land mentioned in the Nac"h, how about [Shishak](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A7)'s campaign, at the time of Rechavam ([Melakhim I 14:25-26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.14.25?lang=bi&lang2=he), [Divrei ha-Yamim II 12:2-9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.12.2?lang=bi&lang2=en))?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any direct mention of them residing in the land after the conquest, but there are echoes/hints that can be found in a few sources:

1. [Shoftim 10:11-12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.10.11-12?lang=bi):

> "And the Lord said to the children of Yisra᾽el, Did not I deliver you from Miżrayim, and from the Emori, from the children of ῾Ammon, and from Pelishtim? The Żidonim also, and ῾Amaleq and Ma῾on, did oppress you; and you cried to me, and I delivered you out of their hand."

On the face of things, the Egyptians mentioned here are the ones that enslaved Bnei Yisrael in Egypt. But this interpretations isn't quite so simple, because not all the people that Bnei Yisrael met during their travels are mentioned here - the Moabites and Midianites are nowhere to be found. Instead, we have here Ma'on and the Tzidonim - entirely different people. Therefore, it is suggested in [this essay](http://chttps://www.knowingfaith.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%91) that the Egyptians here are actually a group that oppressed Am Yisrael post-conquest (sometime in the era of the Shoftim; consider that the text zooms in on particular events and largely skips over most of the timespan of the book).

2. [Shoftim 1:27-33](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.1.27-33?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> "Neither did Menashshe drive out the inhabitants of Bet-she᾽an and its hamlets, nor Ta῾nakh and its hamlets, nor the inhabitants of Dor and its hamlets, nor the inhabitants of Yivle῾am and its hamlets, nor the inhabitants of Megiddo and its hamlets: but the Kena῾ani persisted in dwelling in that land...Neither did Efrayim drive out the Kena῾ani that dwelt in Gezer; but the Kena῾ani dwelt in Gezer among them. Neither did Zevulun drive out the inhabitants of Qitron, nor the inhabitants of Nahalol; but the Kena῾ani dwelt among them, and became tributaries. Neither did Asher drive out the inhabitants of ῾Akko, nor the inhabitants of Żidon, nor of Aĥlav, nor of Akhziv, nor of Ḥelba, nor of Afiq, nor of Reĥov...Neither did Naftali drive out the inhabitants of Bet-shemesh, nor the inhabitants of Bet-῾anat; but he dwelt among the Kena῾ani, the inhabitants of the land: nevertheless the inhabitants of Bet-shemesh and of Bet-῾anat became tributaries to them."

I heard Rabbi Ouri Cherki point this out in a [class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMiEOHrvtZ4) once. It is known from Egyptian documents that the Egyptians only truly cared about controlling specific parts of Canaan: The coastal plain, the valleys (particularly Emek Yizrael) and the northern-most part of the land - this allowed them to form a comfortable path from Egypt all the way to Damascus (where they constantly waged war with [Mitanni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitanni) (see, for example, the descriptions of Thutmose III's and Amenhotep II's Canaanite conquests). The territories that Menashe didn't manage to free are exactly the areas that were key to the Egyptians. Megiddo, in particular, was one of the most important cities in Canaan to the Egyptians (during Thutmose III's time, for example, the Egyptians spent 7 months sieging the city).

3. Names of towns:

There are some names of towns/locations that may be connected to the Egyptians:

a. [Maayan Mei Naftoach](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.15.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) - Possibly connected to Mernephtach or to the [Naftuchim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.10.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) (one of the original Egyptian clans).

b. [Hamichmetet](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.17.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) - possible stemming from the Egyptian name for Egypt: Kemet. Note that Hamichmetet is described as overlooking Shechem, whose king, according to the El-Amarna letters, was the leader of that era's rebellion against the Egyptians, referred to as the "Apiru" - in other words, an Egyptian outpost overlooking such a troublesome city would make sense.

Both were conquered by Yehoshua, but nonetheless may point to Egyptians having been present in those places. Presumably they then retreated to the places not conquered.

One thing to note is that from what archeologists can tell, the Egyptians considered Canaan to be 100% part of Egypt. They called it "Retenu". It is difficult to tell whether the Canaanites saw themselves as Egyptians for we do not have that many Canaanite texts. However, it certainly seems they did not, considering the many times the Canaanites rebelled against the Egyptians (some consider the Apiru to have been some kind of ancient social-change liberty movement) and from the fact that their cultures were so different. In fact, just to communicate with the Canaanites, the Egyptians had to resort to the Middle-Eastern lingua franca and writing style of the time, Akkadian-cuneiform, as opposed to their own Egyptian-hieroglyphics. The Tanach appears to sort-of side with the Canaanites on this point - the land is separate from Egypt (for if we were to say that the land is part of Egypt, then that means that Hashem chalilah never took Am Yisrael out of Egypt). It's possible that for this reason, the Egyptian presence in Canaan is greatly minimized.